# How to set a style properly?

Tags: c#, wpf

My button first was like this:

```
<Button  Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignToolForegroundButton}">
```

but I then had to setup some style triggers for the button visibility. (sorry for the code, I can't manage to format it as should be).

```
  <Button.Style>

   <Style x:Name="ButtonVisibility">
       <Setter Property="Button.Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
         <Style.Triggers>
               <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=StatusDrc, Mode=TwoWay}" Value="En attente" />
                     </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
       <Setter Property="Button.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=StatusDrc, Mode=TwoWay}" Value="En attente" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
       <Setter Property="Button.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                 </MultiDataTrigger>
              </Style.Triggers>
           </Style>

    </Button.Style>
```

My question is how could I keep the style triggers and at the same time, use that `MaterialDesignToolForegroundButton`

Comment: *"I can't manage to format it as should be"* - that is simple. Just remove all the useless whitespaces, and keep only those that are useful, i.e. 4 spaces in the first code line, additional 4 spaces for each indentation.

Comment: Besides that, you seem to be looking for the Style's `BasedOn` property.

Comment: @Clemens Thank you, that did the job :)